# Understanding behaviour of global id in OpenCL

Tags: c#, opencl, emgucv, cloo

OpenCL newbie question

I'm trying to write a kernel to perform some task over rectangular regions of an image.

OpenCL

```
__kernel void GrayBlockSignalSeparation
(
    __global float * rhos
)
{
    const int neighbourhoodSize = 60;

    const int x = get_global_id(0);
    const int y = get_global_id(1);

    rhos[x - 1 + (y-1)*(neighbourhoodSize) ] = x;
}
```

C#

```
private static void GraySignalSeparation
(                         
    ref Image<Gray, float> Signal
)
{
    float[] rhos = new float[(int)(image.Width / 60) * (int)(image.Height / 60)];                
    CLCalc.Program.Variable rhosVar = new CLCalc.Program.Variable(rhos);

    CLCalc.Program.MemoryObject[] args = new CLCalc.Program.MemoryObject[] 
    {                     
        rhosVar
    };
    GraySignalSeparationKernel.Execute(args, new int[] { (int)(image.Width / 60), (int)(image.Height / 60) });

    rhosVar.ReadFromDeviceTo(rhos);

}
```

When I inspect the rho values in the debugger I find that some of them appear to have been missed and are set to zero.

```
[0] 1
[1] 2
[2] 3
[3] 4
[4] 5
[5] 6
[6] 7
[7] 8
[8] 9
[9] 10
[10]    11
[11]    12
[12]    13
[13]    14
[14]    15
[15]    16
[16]    17
[17]    18
[18]    19
[19]    20
[20]    21
[21]    22
[22]    23
[23]    24
[24]    25
[25]    26
[26]    27
[27]    28
[28]    29
[29]    30
[30]    31
[31]    0
[32]    0
[33]    0
[34]    0
[35]    0
[36]    0
[37]    0
[38]    0
[39]    0
[40]    0
[41]    0
[42]    0
[43]    0
[44]    0
[45]    0
[46]    0
[47]    0
[48]    0
[49]    0
[50]    0
[51]    0
[52]    0
[53]    0
[54]    0
[55]    0
[56]    0
[57]    0
[58]    0
[59]    0
[60]    1
[61]    2
[62]    3
[63]    4
[64]    5
[65]    6
[66]    7
[67]    8
[68]    9
[69]    10
[70]    11
[71]    12
[72]    13
[73]    14
[74]    15
[75]    16
[76]    17
[77]    18
[78]    19
[79]    20
[80]    21
[81]    22
[82]    23
[83]    24
[84]    25
[85]    26
[86]    27
[87]    28
[88]    29
[89]    30
[90]    31
[91]    0
[92]    0
[93]    0
[94]    0
[95]    0
[96]    0
[97]    0
[98]    0
[99]    0
[100]   0
[101]   0
[102]   0
[103]   0
[104]   0
[105]   0
[106]   0
[107]   0
[108]   0
[109]   0
[110]   0
[111]   0
[112]   0
[113]   0
[114]   0
[115]   0
[116]   0
[117]   0
[118]   0
[119]   0
[120]   1
[121]   2
[122]   3
[123]   4
[124]   5
[125]   6
[126]   7
[127]   8
[128]   9
[129]   10
[130]   11
[131]   12
[132]   13
[133]   14
[134]   15
[135]   16
[136]   17
[137]   18
[138]   19
[139]   20
[140]   21
[141]   22
[142]   23
[143]   24
[144]   25
[145]   26
[146]   27
[147]   28
[148]   29
[149]   30
[150]   31
[151]   0
[152]   0
[153]   0
[154]   0
[155]   0
[156]   0
[157]   0
[158]   0
[159]   0
[160]   0
[161]   0
[162]   0
[163]   0
[164]   0
[165]   0
[166]   0
[167]   0
[168]   0
[169]   0
[170]   0
[171]   0
[172]   0
[173]   0
[174]   0
[175]   0
[176]   0
[177]   0
[178]   0
[179]   0
[180]   1
[181]   2
[182]   3
[183]   4
[184]   5
[185]   6
[186]   7
[187]   8
[188]   9
[189]   10
[190]   11
[191]   12
[192]   13
[193]   14
[194]   15
[195]   16
[196]   17
[197]   18
[198]   19
[199]   20
[200]   21
[201]   22
[202]   23
[203]   24
[204]   25
[205]   26
[206]   27
[207]   28
[208]   29
[209]   30
[210]   31
[211]   0
[212]   0
[213]   0
[214]   0
[215]   0
[216]   0
[217]   0
[218]   0
[219]   0
[220]   0
[221]   0
[222]   0
[223]   0
[224]   0
[225]   0
[226]   0
[227]   0
[228]   0
[229]   0
[230]   0
[231]   0
[232]   0
[233]   0
[234]   0
[235]   0
[236]   0
[237]   0
[238]   0
[239]   0
[240]   1
[241]   2
[242]   3
[243]   4
[244]   5
[245]   6
[246]   7
[247]   8
[248]   9
[249]   10
[250]   11
[251]   12
[252]   13
[253]   14
[254]   15
[255]   16
[256]   17
[257]   18
[258]   19
[259]   20
[260]   21
[261]   22
[262]   23
[263]   24
[264]   25
[265]   26
[266]   27
[267]   28
[268]   29
[269]   30
[270]   31
[271]   0
[272]   0
[273]   0
[274]   0
[275]   0
[276]   0
[277]   0
[278]   0
[279]   0
[280]   0
[281]   0
[282]   0
[283]   0
[284]   0
[285]   0
[286]   0
[287]   0
[288]   0
[289]   0
[290]   0
[291]   0
[292]   0
[293]   0
[294]   0
[295]   0
[296]   0
[297]   0
[298]   0
[299]   0
[300]   1
[301]   2
[302]   3
[303]   4
[304]   5
[305]   6
[306]   7
[307]   8
[308]   9
[309]   10
[310]   11
[311]   12
[312]   13
[313]   14
[314]   15
[315]   16
[316]   17
[317]   18
[318]   19
[319]   20
[320]   21
[321]   22
[322]   23
[323]   24
[324]   25
[325]   26
[326]   27
[327]   28
[328]   29
[329]   30
[330]   31
[331]   0
[332]   0
[333]   0
[334]   0
[335]   0
[336]   0
[337]   0
[338]   0
[339]   0
[340]   0
[341]   0
[342]   0
[343]   0
[344]   0
[345]   0
[346]   0
[347]   0
[348]   0
[349]   0
[350]   0
[351]   0
[352]   0
[353]   0
[354]   0
[355]   0
[356]   0
[357]   0
[358]   0
[359]   0
[360]   1
[361]   2
[362]   3
[363]   4
[364]   5
[365]   6
[366]   7
[367]   8
[368]   9
[369]   10
[370]   11
[371]   12
[372]   13
[373]   14
[374]   15
[375]   16
[376]   17
[377]   18
[378]   19
[379]   20
[380]   21
[381]   22
[382]   23
[383]   24
[384]   25
[385]   26
[386]   27
[387]   28
[388]   29
[389]   30
[390]   31
[391]   0
[392]   0
[393]   0
[394]   0
[395]   0
[396]   0
[397]   0
[398]   0
[399]   0
[400]   0
[401]   0
[402]   0
[403]   0
[404]   0
[405]   0
[406]   0
[407]   0
[408]   0
[409]   0
[410]   0
[411]   0
[412]   0
[413]   0
[414]   0
[415]   0
[416]   0
[417]   0
[418]   0
[419]   0
[420]   1
[421]   2
[422]   3
[423]   4
[424]   5
[425]   6
[426]   7
[427]   8
[428]   9
[429]   10
[430]   11
[431]   12
[432]   13
[433]   14
[434]   15
[435]   16
[436]   17
[437]   18
[438]   19
[439]   20
[440]   21
[441]   22
[442]   23
[443]   24
[444]   25
[445]   26
[446]   27
[447]   28
[448]   29
[449]   30
[450]   31
[451]   0
[452]   0
[453]   0
[454]   0
[455]   0
[456]   0
[457]   0
[458]   0
[459]   0
[460]   0
[461]   0
[462]   0
[463]   0
[464]   0
[465]   0
[466]   0
[467]   0
[468]   0
[469]   0
[470]   0
[471]   0
[472]   0
[473]   0
[474]   0
[475]   0
[476]   0
[477]   0
[478]   0
[479]   0
[480]   1
[481]   2
[482]   3
[483]   4
[484]   5
[485]   6
[486]   7
[487]   8
[488]   9
[489]   10
[490]   11
[491]   12
[492]   13
[493]   14
[494]   15
[495]   16
[496]   17
[497]   18
[498]   19
[499]   20
[500]   21
[501]   22
[502]   23
[503]   24
[504]   25
[505]   26
[506]   27
[507]   28
[508]   29
[509]   30
[510]   31
[511]   0
[512]   0
[513]   0
[514]   0
[515]   0
[516]   0
[517]   0
[518]   0
[519]   0
[520]   0
[521]   0
[522]   0
[523]   0
[524]   0
[525]   0
[526]   0
[527]   0
[528]   0
[529]   0
[530]   0
[531]   0
[532]   0
[533]   0
[534]   0
[535]   0
[536]   0
[537]   0
[538]   0
[539]   0
[540]   1
[541]   2
[542]   3
[543]   4
[544]   5
[545]   6
[546]   7
[547]   8
[548]   9
[549]   10
[550]   11
[551]   12
[552]   13
[553]   14
[554]   15
[555]   16
[556]   17
[557]   18
[558]   19
[559]   20
[560]   21
[561]   22
[562]   23
[563]   24
[564]   25
[565]   26
[566]   27
[567]   28
[568]   29
[569]   30
[570]   31
[571]   0
[572]   0
[573]   0
[574]   0
[575]   0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
rhos[x + (y)*(correct_stride) ] = x;
```

where correct_stride = image.Width / 60;

The global id's are indexed from 0 to upwards. It forms a sequence like 0,1,2,3,4... and not 1,2,3,4... If we are strict you are invoking undefined behavior as your first index performs a write outside the memory you originally allocated.

Also

```
float[] rhos = new float[(int)(image.Width / 60) * (int)(image.Height / 60)];
```

Worries me a bit. Is your image exactly 3600x3600? Otherwise your stride is wrong. The neighbourhoodsize variable must be the width of the picture segment you are using.

Comment: I've tried using rhos[x + (y)*(neighbourhoodSize) ] = x; unfortunately this has not fixed the problem. I still have the blocks of zeros in my rhos. Just ofset by one place now.

Comment: My image is not exactly 3600x3600, I'm planning to handle the case of pixels being indexed outside the image by clipping them to the image.

Comment: Rest of the zeroes probably arise from the too large of a stride, I edited the main post. You need to use the Image.Width/60 instead of just 60 as your stride when you write the data.